# A brother G is 6 years older than his younger brother L. The first digit in G's age is twice..

Tags: algebra-precalculus, systems-of-equations, linear-diophantine-equations

> A brother $G$ is 6 years older than his younger brother $L$. The first digit in G's age is twice the second digit in L's age. The second digit in G's age is twice the first digit in L's age. Find their ages.

I assumed that:
$G = L + 6$

and G's age is compose by two digits:
$G = XY
$
and L's age is composed by two digits as well:
$L = KT
$

and we know that:
$X = 2T$ and $Y = 2K$

How can I proceed to find their ages?

Comment: You could instead write the ages as $a10 + b$ where a,b are digits from 0 to 9

Comment: why there is a 10 after the a?

Comment: Because it's the tens place, human ages are on average a tens place plus a ones place due to the decimal system

Comment: ok thanks, and how can I proceed with the rest?

Comment: Marcus got to what I was hinting to

Comment: @DietrichBurde Done, it was to attract people ;)

Comment: Should we assume that the ages are only 2 digits?

Comment: Yes probably you have to assume them

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $G = 10a + b$ and $L = 10c + d$, their ages.

We are given that $G = 6 + L$, $a = 2d$, and $b = 2c$.

Solving this system (and keeping $a,b,c,d$ bound to the $0-9$ range), we have $a=4, b=8, c=4, d=2$, so $G=48$, and $L=42$

Comment: Do I have to make a system with the following equations:
$10a+b = 10c + d$ and $a = 2d$ and $b= 2c$ ?

Comment: $G = 6 + L$ implies $10a + b = 6 + 10c + d$, but otherwise yes.

Comment: In the system I reach a point where I have $19d - 8c = 6$ and $a=2d$ and $b=2c$, can you please give me a hint on how to proceed?

Comment: @Alcakram You can rearrange that to $d = (6 + 8c)/19$. What value of $c$ in the range $0$ through $9$ makes $d$ an integer?